# Puppeteer: unable to select and click button using data attribute

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have this code for a button that will have id and class generated dynamically.

```
<a role="button" class="_42ft _4jy0 _6lti _4jy6 _4jy2 selected _51sy" href="#" ajaxify="/reg/spotlight/" id="u_0_2_zs" data-testid="open-registration-form-button" rel="async">Create account</a>
```

I'm trying to select and click it using puppeteer but without success, I've tried this code but the script will end with an error because the element isn't selected.

```
(async () => {
    // 
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    //
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    //
    await page.goto('https://example.com/login', {
        waitUntil: ['load', 'networkidle2']
    });
    //
    const cookieButton = await page.$('[data-cookiebanner="accept_button"]');
    await cookieButton.click();
    //

    const profileButton = await page.$('[data-testid="open-registration-form-button"]')
    await profileButton.click();

})();
```

Is there a solution to select the button and click it?

Comment: I don't see a reason this shouldn't work with the lone element taken out of context, assuming your cookiebanner click is working. Have you tried `waitForSelector('[data-testid="open-registration-form-button"]')`? I can only guess without seeing the page itself or a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @ggorlen no I haven't tried to wait until the selector is available. It's strange also for me because the button is part of a form that is working if tested. using puppetree. The beahviour of the button is to open an ajax loaded iframe that will display the registration form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there are dynamically rendered css selectors on pages, I look to use the xpath route.

Step 1 => Find the xPath through inspect element, right click the element > "copy xpath"

Step 2 => Use the page.waitForXPath(xpath[, options]) and page.$x() function found in puppeteer documentation https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pagexexpression

Step 3 => Run/Test your code